# AWS Athena returns 0 records for non-hive style data with partitions

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have created a table with partitions.
The location for partitions is different from the source from where partitions are created.

The partitions are created successfully and I can see folders forming in the s3 location for the operations on partitions.

However, when I run select all query, I get 0 records.

I am trying to read data from a csv using a non-hive partition creation format.

Regards,
Aarushi

Comment: Are you sure  that "location" is correct in your DDL statement?

Comment: Thank you . That was the problem. All resources suggest different. But I corrected by adding the data source location to ALTER ADD PARTITION query

Answer (score -1):

My issue was resolved by adding the data source location in ALTER TABLE query, instead of partitioned data output location that has been suggested in the documentation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).